# MySQL synatx errors within Store Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

This is an older store procedure code that I found and am trying to use within my project.  I searched for the proper syntax to use with MySql 5.6 but I have not been able to resolve this issue.  Can someone point me in the right direction with this please?  Thanks in advance.  Right now I'm getting error 1064 on almost every line.  I tried removing the BEGIN/END and I'll get an unexpected IF error.  Help pls

Here is the original code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_tbl_login]
@LoginId int=null,
@LoginName varchar(100)=null,
@Email varchar(100)=null,
@Username varchar(20)=null,
@Password varchar(20)=null,
@Rights int=null,
@Mode varchar(25)
AS

IF (@Mode='Insert') 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE Username=@Username)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tbl_login(LoginName,Email,Username,Password,Rights,ModifiedDate) VALUES(@LoginName,@Email,@Username,@Password,@Rights,getdate())
END

IF (@Mode='View') 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tbl_login
END

IF (@Mode='ViewByID') 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE LoginId = @LoginId
END

IF (@Mode='ChkLogin') 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE Username = @Username and Password = @Password
END

IF (@Mode='Update') 
BEGIN
UPDATE [tbl_login]
SET [LoginName] = @LoginName
  ,[Email] = @Email
  ,[Username] = @Username
  ,[Password] = @Password
  ,[Rights] = @Rights
  ,[ModifiedDate] = getdate()
WHERE LoginId = @LoginId
END

IF (@Mode='Delete') 
BEGIN
DELETE FROM [tbl_login] WHERE LoginId = @LoginId
END
GO
```

I have tried it with & without the "BEGIN/END".  If I douse them it stops at the Here is where I am right now with it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_tbl_login`
(LoginId int,
LoginName varchar(100),
Email varchar(100),
Username varchar(20),
Password varchar(20),
Rights int,
Mode varchar(25))


IF (@Mode='Insert') THEN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE Username=@Username) THEN

BEGIN
INSERT INTO tbl_login(LoginName,Email,Username,Password,Rights,ModifiedDate) VALUES(@LoginName,@Email,@Username,@Password,@Rights,getdate())

END

IF (@Mode='View') THEN

SELECT * FROM tbl_login


IF (@Mode='ViewByID') THEN
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE LoginId = @LoginId
END

IF (@Mode='ChkLogin') 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE Username = @Username and Password = @Password
END

IF (@Mode='Update') 
BEGIN
UPDATE tbl_login
SET [LoginName] = @LoginName
  ,[Email] = @Email
  ,[Username] = @Username
  ,[Password] = @Password
  ,[Rights] = @Rights
  ,[ModifiedDate] = getdate()
WHERE LoginId = @LoginId
END

IF (@Mode='Delete') 
BEGIN
DELETE FROM [tbl_login] WHERE LoginId = @LoginId
END
GO
```

Comment: You are working with a SQL Server stored proc as evidenced by GETDATE().  The MySQL equivalent is CURRENT_DATE.  It will take some time to re-do the whole thing.

Comment: Okay - thanks!  I will get MSSql and see if that works

Comment: I still get syntax errors when using the import/export wizard. I'm in the process of trying to debug and rewrite as needed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated